# How to use a static library with node-gyp on Windows?

Tags: c++, node.js, linker, node-modules, node-gyp

I am trying to link a static library using `node-gyp` in order to use it as a native `node` addon. However, when I run `node-gyp rebuild` I get the following linking error:

```sh
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl mylibengine::criticalZvalue(double)" (?criticalZvalue@mylibengine@@YANN@Z)
```

Which is immediately followed by:

```sh
C:\Users\Mihai\Desktop\msp-addon\build\Release\mylib-addon.node : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals [C:\Users\Mihai\Desktop\mylib-addon\build\mylib-addon.vcxproj
```

The `binding.gyp` looks like:

```py
{
    'targets': [{
        'target_name': 'mylib-addon',
        'cflags!': [ '-fno-exceptions' ],
        'cflags_cc!': [ '-fno-exceptions' ],

        'include_dirs': [
            '<!@(node -p \"require(\'node-addon-api\').include\")',
            '<(module_root_dir)/dependencies/mylib/include/'
        ],

        'sources': [
            'src/MyLibNode.cpp'
        ],

        'dependencies': [
            '<!(node -p \"require(\'node-addon-api\').gyp\")'
        ],

        'libraries': [
            '<(module_root_dir)/dependencies/mylib/lib/x64/libmylib.a'
        ],

        'defines': [ 'NAPI_DISABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS' ]
    }]
}
```

The `MyLibNode.cpp` looks like this:

```cpp
#include <napi.h>
#include "engine.h"

Napi::Object InitAll(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports)
{
    // Temporary check to make sure `libmylib.a` works.
    mylibengine::criticalZvalue(.3);

    return exports;
}

NODE_API_MODULE(mspaddon, InitAll)
```

I am sure that the linker can find `libmylib.a`, because when I change the name of the library (e.g., to `disabled.a`) I get a different error saying that the input file cannot be opened. However, it is *unable to resolve the external symbol*.

I found a similar, unanswered, question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39408839/node-gyp-static-library-on-windows). Answers to other questions indicate adding the full library path to `libraries`, but I don't think that's the problem for my scenario.

**Why can't `node-gyp` resolve the external symbol?**

---

**Additional information:**

- I am running Windows 10
- I tested that the library works, by trying to use it with `g++`, as described below

I have the following project structure:

```
├───build
└───dependencies
    └───mylib
        ├───include
        └───lib
            └───x64
```

- inside `dependencies/mylib/include` I have a header file called `engine.h` which contains:

```cpp
#pragma once

namespace mylibengine
{
    double criticalZvalue(double quantile);
}
```

- within `dependencies/mylib/lib/x64` I have a static library named `libmylib.a`
- in the root directory I have a file called `main.cpp` which contains:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <engine.h>


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Main working." << "\n";
    std::cout << mylibengine::criticalZvalue(.3) << "\n";
}
```

I can link the library in the executable as:

```sh
g++ -obuild/main main.cpp -Idependencies/mylib/include/ -Ldependencies/mylib/lib/x64/ -lmylib
```

At this point, running `main.exe` will output just fine:

```sh
Main working.
-0.524002
```

Comment: Since your `MyLibNode.cpp` calls only `double mylibengine::criticalZvalue(double)` it cannot be responsible for an undefined reference to:
`double mspengine::criticalZvalue(double)`. It seems your posted code, in which `mspengine` does not appear, is not the code actually in error.

Comment: Sorry about the `mspengine` namespace. The error is `LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl mylibengine::criticalZvalue(double)`. I will update the question the reflect this.

Comment: @Mihai i know that this is an old question, but is there any progress with the issue?

Comment: @simon_tulia, see my answer below. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the question above, the static library `libmylib.a` is compiled using the `g++` from a `mingw64` installation. However, `node-gyp` uses the Microsoft C and C++ (MSVC) runtime libraries.

It seems (i.e., see [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1240)) that `node-gyp` does not support `mingw64`. In the issue linked, someone indicates

> [mingw uses its own name mangling scheme that makes interoperability impossible.](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1240#issuecomment-309705630)

which is also the issue encountered in this question (i.e., `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol`). The solution is to create the static library using the Microsoft toolchain and then the symbols will be correctly resolved by the linker.